# What is wrong with my photorealistic procedural chocolate texture?

Tags: node-editor, photorealism

I want a chocolate texture with that tiny scratches and crumbs (upper left). After spending some time to copy node by node from [this example](https://blenderartists.org/t/trying-out-some-chocolate-materials/1249709/3), I can't barely see any difference to the simple one bsdf (upper right).

What am I missing?
[image: pic]

HDRI source: [HDRI Haven > Venice Sunrise](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri/?h=venice_sunrise)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This node setup isn't really the best to use if you want the crumbly scratched look, if you look at the image that the node setup was posted with the chocolate is very smooth.
You can adjust the black and white ColorRamp going into the roughness of the material to get some smears to show, but it won't really get you any farther than that.

I suggest you make your own material, and use surface imperfection textures for the roughness and bump, that will give you the scratched up look you want.

Comment: Oh, and also use the surface imperfections texture as a mix factor for your base color and a whitish one.

Comment: > make your own material
Thank you @Egorobi . Any hint for a close point to start with? I just found out that the proper term for the smears is "chocolate bloom"