# How to fix my procedural chocolate bloom nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

My goal
[image: Text]

My achievement
[image: Text]

My problem:
Most nodes are guessed because I can't properly follow the [0]tutorial since my version of blender is newer[1]

[0] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KO_qkM93q8

[1] [Downgrade to what version to cover most tutorials?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220608/downgrade-to-what-version-to-cover-most-tutorials?noredirect=1#comment372536_220608)

### Update

I followed @Blunder's excellent instructions step by step, yet I'm not getting the same result. In particular the bloom of sugar and fat seem flat and even glossy instead being additional material on the chocolate coat. What am I missing?

[image: txt]

[image: txt]

[image]

Comment: The tutorial is on V.2.80.75. you can download it here https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

Comment: @Gorgious That's exactly what I was advised **against** to do in [1]

Comment: Their point is valid, and if you have the time to do so, try in the newer version. Now if you want to achieve the result in a minimal amount of time, you can follow the tutorial using the same version, then try recreating in a newer version once you know how to do it. It's really your choice in the end, there is no bad way to go about it in my opinion, so long as you take the time to understand what each new node brings to the shader tree, and go out of your way to try new things when you feel like it

Comment: @Gorgious It's been a month and I still have not the slightest clue what I'm doing :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216001/what-is-wrong-with-my-photorealistic-procedural-chocolate-texture

Comment: Yeah some say it takes 10 000 hours in a particular field to become an expert ;) Your current result already looks good to me, you might want to lower the distance of the bump node and play a bit with a 3 point light system to make it pop. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you did here is that **you used a *painted scratched metal* shader for *chocolate* - and that 1 to 1 including the metallic value(!)**. This results in delicious chocolate for robots ... or tasty chocolate robots? ;-)

You can use the procedural imperfections from this shader setup for the chocolate bloom and (in other cases) you can use the *Metallic* value in Eevee to fake colors (like lipstick, hair shading, etc). But I would not recommend *Metallic* for chocolate.

You will get a much better result if you use the ***Roughness* value for the chocolate instead**.

Let's start simple and make a **simple chocolate** shader.

- make a chocolate bar. In *Edit* mode, scale down the default cube, subdivide it, select the 4 top faces, insect them and pull them up a bit. In *Object* mode, add a *Bevel* modifier to make it less blocky (Width, 0.01m, 3 segments, Limited to Angle, 26°)
- then set up a simple shader with little ***Base Color* variation** and ***Roughness* variation**. This can be done easily with *Noise* textures. Last but not least, give it a bit of ***Subsurface Scattering*** to make it look more organic. No metal is here involved ;-)  [image: simple chocolate shader]

Now let's evolve this to the **sophisticated chocolate with imperfections** shader.

- add the shader node setup for the procedural scratches (of painted metal) from the tutorial video and adjust it a bit
- most important: **don't use the *Metallic* slot but use the *Roughness* slot**
- adjust the colors of *Color Ramp* for the base color as you like. Insert a light brown color for the imperfections
- add a *Noise* texture and *Mix RGB* node for the *Base Color* (top right in the screenshot) to create some darker areas as shown in the reference image
- (optional) add seams and UV unwrap the chocolate bar to get rid of texture compression at the sides
- use an HDR image for the world background (and for Eevee an extra light).
  [image: chocolate shader with imperfections]

The shader in this example is from the linked video with the "Voronoi Cracks" update for Blender 2.81, plus some noise in base color and UV mapping for little rotation as described above.

**Rendered example** (Cycles, 128 samples, Adaptive Sampling, NLM denoiser (checkbox), 50% size)
[image: rendered example]

Comment: Maybe a little less SSS, as the results look somewhat more like milk-chocolate, rather than the dark chocolate shown in the picture

Comment: @Blunder Thank you so much. I'm not getting the same result as you. Updated the question accordingly.